# Join two dataframes on Date index

Tags: python, pandas, join

I am trying to `join` two `dataframes` in a `for-loop`. The data looks like this:

```
df1
                 Close Symbol
Date
2010-08-10    7.954775   AAPL
2010-08-11    7.672046   AAPL
2010-08-12    7.721110   AAPL
2010-08-13    7.638622   AAPL  
...
  
table_df
                 Close Symbol
Date
2010-08-10   39.996582    WMT
2010-08-11   39.305542    WMT
2010-08-12   38.851002    WMT
2010-08-13   38.827896    WMT
...
```

I try to `join` them like this:

```
df1.join(table_df)
```

But I get an `exception`. I also tried:

```
df1.join(table_df, on = 'Date')
```

But that doesn't work either.

Comment: Is `Date` a column of the dataframe, or its index?

Comment: You can see it is an index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `left_index` and `right_index` arguments of the [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method.

```
df1.merge(table_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)

             Close_x Symbol_x    Close_y Symbol_y
Date                                             
2010-08-10  7.954775     AAPL  39.996582      WMT
2010-08-11  7.672046     AAPL  39.305542      WMT
2010-08-12  7.721110     AAPL  38.851002      WMT
2010-08-13  7.638622     AAPL  38.827896      WMT
```

Extra tip: you can also modify the suffixes for same-name columns with the argument `suffixes`.

Comment: Doesn't merge just go row by row and merges no matter what? I need to make sure that the two rows are "merged" only-if their dates correspond. Hence the join?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what your desired output is. Are the two dataframes stacked vertically or horizontally? Could you please provide the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) them with `how='inner'` (to ensure join only-if their dates correspond) and specify the index level name `Date` to join on both dataframes.  Also give new suffixes to the conflicting (same) column labels, as follows:

```
df1.join(table_df, how='inner', on='Date', lsuffix='_APPL', rsuffix='_WMT')
```

**Result:**

```
            Close_APPL Symbol_APPL  Close_WMT Symbol_WMT
Date                                                    
2010-08-10    7.954775        AAPL  39.996582        WMT
2010-08-11    7.672046        AAPL  39.305542        WMT
2010-08-12    7.721110        AAPL  38.851002        WMT
2010-08-13    7.638622        AAPL  38.827896        WMT
```

Comment: As I commented in the other solution, doesn't merge just append the two rows regardless of whether the index matches?

Comment: BTW, your are appending. I need the data for each date to live on one row.

Comment: @Ivan  Ok, clear now, you want to join them vertically.  How do you want to handle the conflicting column labels ?

Comment: @Ivan   Updated my solution.  Please take a look.